# Apply a constructor in a do context in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor

Given the following declarations

```hs
data MyCustomString = MyCustomString String deriving (Show, Eq)

getSomeString :: IO String
```

I'd like to process the output of `getSomeString` into a `IO MyCustomString` in a `do` context:

```hs
do
    cs_one <- getSomeString
    cs_two <- getSomeString

    -- at this point, `cs_one` and `cs_two` are of type `String`
    -- how to construct them into `MyCustomString` instead with no additional lines?
```

However, `getSomeString` returns an `String` and not an `MyCustomString`. How could I use the `MyCustomString` constructor so that both `cs_one` and `cs_two` are, at this point in the code, of type `MyCustomString` ?

I've tried this to no avail:

```hs
-- this does not work
do
    MyCustomString cs_one <- getSomeString
    MyCustomString cs_two <- getSomeString

-- this neither
do
    cs_one <- MyCustomString getSomeString
    cs_two <- MyCustomString getSomeString
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way is:

```
do
    cs_one <- MyCustomString <$> getSomeString
    cs_two <- MyCustomString <$> getSomeString
```

The `<$>` operator is a synonym for `fmap` and has the signature:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Since monads are functors, it specializes to the monad `IO` as:

```
(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

which applies a function "under" the IO monad, in this case turning your `IO String` into an `IO MyCustomString`.

Comment: Brilliant. I definitely need to practice my functors :)

Answer (score 5):

Since `getSomeString` returns an `IO String`, and the constructor expects a naked string, you can't just apply the constructor to the result of `getSomeString`

First you have to get that string actually produced, and then you can wrap it in the constructor:

```
do
    cs_one_str <- getSomeString
    let cs_one = MyCustomString cs_one_str
    ...
```

Or you can use the `fmap` function, which does the exact same thing as the snippet above:

```
    cs_one <- fmap MyCustomString getSomeString
```

Or its operator alias `<$>`:

```
    cs_one <- MyCustomString <$> getSomeString
```